# Show QR code in an image Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, qr-code

I am working in an app that READ/CREATE QR codes using ZXing.net.Mobile.Forms library , i got everything to work but for the CREATING part i want to display it as an image.

so far am just adding it to the page ( see code below )

```
  ZXingBarcodeImageView barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView();


  barcode.BarcodeFormat = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
  barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 700;
  barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 700;
  barcode.BarcodeOptions.Margin = 10;
  barcode.BarcodeValue = txtQR.Text; // Text to be rendered to a QR CODE

  //StackPage name of the StackLayout
  StackPage.Children.Add(barcode);
```

Instead of [ StackPage.add(barcode) ];

i want something like this :

image.source = barcode;

any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: ZXingBarcodeImageView inherits from Image, so it is itself an Image.  Why don't you just want to insert it in the page?

Comment: @Jason because if i keep it this way, every time a user generate a QR code, that barcode will be added, while i want it to be replaced

Comment: Just replace the Image control you already have with a ZxIngBarcodeImageView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How Jason says `ZXingBarcodeImageView` inherits from Image, so it is itself an Image. So you should add it into a View. First, create a View in another file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
 x:Class="QRManager.Views.QRResult">
    <ContentView.Content>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Now, in your MainPage add this View using `xmlns:local` for your namespace :

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QRManager.Views;assembly=QRManager"
         x:Class="QRManager.Views.QRGeneratorPage"
         Title="Generator Page">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <StackLayout>
                <Entry x:Name="contentEntry" TextColor="Black"
                   Placeholder="Texto" PlaceholderColor="Silver" 
                   Keyboard="Text" FontSize="18" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                <Button Text="Generar QR" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#2196F3" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <local:QRResult x:Name="qrResult" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Finally in you code behind set your View with `ZXingBarcodeImageView` like this:

```cs
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         if (contentEntry.Text != string.Empty)
         {
             barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
             {
                 HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                 VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
             };
             barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
             barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 500;
             barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 500;
             barcode.BarcodeValue = contentEntry.Text.Trim();
////////// SEE HERE //////////
             qrResult.Content = barcode;
         }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Alert", "Introduzca el valor que desea convertir código QR", "OK");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            DisplayAlert("Alert", "Introduzca el valor que desea convertir código QR", "OK");
        }
}
```

For more information see [this repository](https://github.com/wilsonvargas/QRManager/) with a sample.

Comment: Excellent response, @Wilson Vargas. Your solution works like a charm. The only issue is when you click again on the "Generate QR" button, after you have clicked once, the application crashes.

Comment: @Joel: please post the exception you get as a new stackoverflow question